# How to define an array in OpenAPI 3.0.3 that cannot contain null objects

Tags: openapi

I have the following schema defined in OpenAPI 3.0.3:

```json
    CreateUsersRequest:
      type: object
      required:
        - users
      properties:
        users:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/User'
            
    User:
      type: object
      required:
        - FirstName
        - LastName
      properties:
        FirstName:
          type: string
          description: User first name
        LastName:
          type: string
          description: User last name
```

Is it possible to define `null` objects in array are not allowed?

This instance should fail:

```json
    [
        {
            "FirstName": "John",
            "LastName": "Smith"
        },
        null,
        {
            "FirstName": "Thomas",
            "LastName": "Mann"
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your full OpenAPI description, it appears the schema you have defined and the instance you've given are giving you the expected result.

I recreated your description with two examples. The first is without a `null` object and the second with the `null` object and you can see the linter I'm using ([Redocly CLI](https://www.redocly.com)) is reporting the warning on the second example with the `null` object defined. Because the `items` keyword is referencing a schema object defined as `type: object`, no other data types are acceptable for this schema.

Where are you experiencing the behavior you've reported? From a tool? From swagger site?  Can you share more about how you're validating the request body?

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: stack
  version: 1.0.0
  license:
    name: MIT
    url: https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
servers:
  - url: http://127.0.0.1:8080
    description: Local server
security: []
paths:
  '/thing':
    post: 
      summary: Request body with examples
      operationId: CreateUserRequest
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/CreateUserRequest'
            examples:
              array_no_null_objects:
                summary: An example of an array with no null objects
                value:
                  users:
                    - FirstName: "John"
                      LastName: "Doe"
                    - FirstName: "Jane"
                      LastName: "Doe"
              array_with_null_object:
                summary: An example of an array with a null object
                value:
                  users:
                    - FirstName: "John"
                      LastName: "Doe"
                    - null
                    - FirstName: "Jane"
                      LastName: "Doe"
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
        '400':
          description: Bad Request
components:
  schemas:
    CreateUserRequest:
      type: object
      required:
        - users
      properties:
        users:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/User'
    User: 
      type: object
      required:
        - FirstName
        - LastName
      properties:
        FirstName:
          type: string
          description: User first name
        LastName:
          type: string
          description: User last name
```

---

[image: results]